# UnauthorizedAccessException due to pipeline created folders as root

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I'm having a pipeline in azure devops that is supposed to be executed on a linux agent.
One task in this pipeline is to run parasoft static code analysis.
We are using a docker container that includes parasoft and which is executin g a bash script to compile our sources and run sca.

My issue is, that on the next run of the pipeline, I'll get an error because it is impossible to checkout the code from git. The reason for that is, during the build with cmake some directories will be created as root.

Here is the related task of the pipeline

```
   - task: Bash@3
     displayName: "Run sca"
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         docker run -t -v "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/host" --platform=linux/amd64  -w /host/ containerregistry.azurecr.io/diag/parasoft:2.8.0 /bin/bash -c "\
         cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug && \
         cpptestcli -localsettings /host/parasoft.properties -config \"someconfig\" \
         -bdf /host/build/compile_commands.json -report /host/sca-report -include \"host/src/**/*.cpp\" \
         "
```

Here is the content of the folder after the docker run

```
completed:agent@host:~/az_agent/_work/1/s$ ll
total 100
drwxr-xr-x 16 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 16:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x  6 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:37 ../
drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root   4096 Dez 23 15:38 build/
drwxr-xr-x  2 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:31 cmake/
-rw-r--r--  1 agent  agents  994 Dez 23 15:31 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   4605 Dez 23 15:42 c++test_static_problems.txt
drwxr-xr-x  7 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:31 diagmaster/
drwxr-xr-x  5 agent  agents 4096 Dez 22 12:47 doc/
drwxr-xr-x  2 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:31 docker/
drwxr-xr-x  5 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:31 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  6 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:31 gen/
drwxr-xr-x  8 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:37 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 agent  agents   70 Dez 23 15:31 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 agent  agents 1478 Dez 23 15:31 parasoft.properties
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 Dez 23 15:38 parasoft_workspace/
drwxr-xr-x  2 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:37 pipelines/
-rw-r--r--  1 agent  agents  723 Dez 23 15:31 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:31 src/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 agent  agents  640 Dez 23 16:14 test.sh*
drwxr-xr-x  3 agent  agents 4096 Dez 23 15:31 utils/
```

If I change the ownership manually e.g. by this command the next execution of the pipeline works without issues.

```
sudo chown -R --reference=cmake *
```

Of sourse I don't want to run this command in my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the issue now focuses on the error 'UnauthorizedAccessException due to pipeline created folders as root'.

You could try to use things like this to give permission to the run agent.

```
chown -R agent:agents *
```

Then the issue is supposed to resolve.

Comment: The chown wouzd require 'sudo' in order to change ownership. Sudo cannot be used within pipeline because of security concerns and it is also not possible to pass the root password.